# Monitor Connection via Adapter - Any benefits/detriments?

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport

I have a new graphics card that has

- 1x DVI
- 1x HDMI
- 3x DisplayPort

However, at present, I only have two monitors - both using DVI.

The three options available to me are:

- Hook up one monitor (the main monitor?) via DVI, and the second to DP via an adapter
- Hook up both monitors to DP via an adapter

Is there any performance benefit/detriment to hooking up through an adapter, over direct into the DVI port? For reference, I use my main monitor for gaming.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage in using an extra adaptor in this case.

Thus I would connect one DVI monitor directly to DVI.

The other can be connected to either DP or HDMI, but since HDMI is more of less just DVI+sound I would use a cheap adaptor for that one.